# Is "jsonString.split('\\').join('\\\\')" needed to parse json string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I want to know risks when I remove a part of legacy codes that I've taken over in my position.

The legacy codes are very widely used in our system and I'm faced with a problem that occurs when parsing a json string to json object in javascipt codes of the legacy code that uses JSON.parse(jsonString). the problem occurs with values in json string containing double quotation in it. the following is the part of the code that makes problem. (It's simply modified, but it makes sense here.)

```
var jsonString = "{\"name\" : \"" +value+ "\"}";
var temp = jsonString.split("\\").join("\\\\");
var jsonObject = JSON.parse(temp);
```

And if I input a value, `"PARK\"S MEDIA"`, then I see the following error on the console of my browser, which is thrown from the line 3 of the code above.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token S in JSON at position 18

The part of the code that I want to remove is the line 2.

```
var temp = jsonString.split("\\").join("\\\\");
```

I really don't understand why it is here. I know what split-join does, but does it make sense here?? Would I get some potential problems if I remove this code?

As I mentioned at first, this code is used very widely, by hundreds of codes in our system. So It's very risky that I carelessly modify any of them and there's no one I can ask about it, so I'm writing this. Can anyone help me?

Comment: In your example, the entire `jsonString.split("\\").join("\\\\");` is effectively a no-op, as there are no backslashes in `jsonString` in the first place. So `split("\\")` will return an array with one entry (the original string, unchanged), and `join` will return the original string (unchanged).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for the comment. yes, the split-join doesn't affect the original string that has no backslashes. but even with backslashes, it result in double backslashes and it makes the parsing error. PARK\"S MEDIA => {"name" : "PARK\\"S MEDIA"} => error.

Comment: Yes. If you have a valid JSON string that contains a backslash, that code will make the string *invalid* JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that a backslash in a string literal is an escape character, it isn't part of the string. What goes in the actual string depends on the character that follows the backslash. E.g., `"foo\\bar"` is a string literal that defines the string `foo\bar`; `"foo\"bar"` is a string literal that defines the string `foo"bar`. Etc.

The code `jsonString.split("\\").join("\\\\");` would split a string into an array, separating them at each backslash (and removing the backslash), then rejoin the array back into a string with *two* backslashes in between teh entries. E.g., it converts one backslash to two throughout the string. (There are better ways to do that.)

In your example string, that code is effectively a no-op, as there are no backslashes in `jsonString` at all. So `split("\\")` will return an array with one entry (the original string, unchanged), and `join` will return the original string (unchanged).

> And if I input a value, `"PARK\"S MEDIA"`, then I see the following error on the console of my browser, which is thrown from the line 3 of the code above.
>
> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token `S` in JSON at position 18

It's not clear whether you mean in a string literal or actually in the JSON.

If you put that in your string literal, for instance:

```
var jsonString = "{\"name\" : \"PARK\"S MEDIA\"}";
```

the string is `{"name" : "PARK"S MEDIA"}`, which is invalid JSON because the `"` after `K` ends the string, and then the next character must be whitespace, a `}`, or `,`.

If the JSON contains that, e.g.

```
{"name": "PARK\"S MEDIA"}
```

...then the code will take that valid JSON and convert it into this **invalid** JSON:

```
{"name": "PARK\\"S MEDIA"}
```

...and you'll get a parsing error on the `S` for the same reason as the above: The backslash in the JSON no longer escapes the `"`, and so the `"` ends the string and the `S` is invalid.

> ...does it make sense here?

Only if the original string (not string literal!) has single backslashes where you want double backslashes. More likely, the author didn't understand the difference between a string and the literal that defines it.

Should you remove it? If the code is working, that suggests either:

1. None of the strings contains any backslashes and so the code isn't doing anything useful, or
2. Strings *do* contain backslashes and so that code is doubling them.

Whether #2 is a good thing or not depends entirely on the strings.

We can't tell you whether you can remove it, but the fundamental answer to *"Is "jsonString.split('\').join('\\')" needed to parse json string in javascript?"* is no. That doesn't mean the code isn't doing something important in *your* case, though. Or it could just be pointless and perhaps even causing extra backslashes in things.